# Sweetalert2 multiple input validation

Tags: validation, input, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I'm trying to have multiple forms inside mutiple modals, as I've read I have to use `swal.mixin` with queue, all of these forms have multiple inputs inside.

I've already done that, but can't find a way to validate all of these forms, any sugestion?

Here's my code:

```
    swal.mixin({
    confirmButtonText: 'Siguiente',
    buttonsStyling: false,
  }).queue([
    {
      html: 
        "<form class='formulario' action='' method='post'>" +

          "<div class='fila'>"+
            "<img src='src/images/svg/icons/person.svg' class='imagen'/>"+
            "<input id='name' class='espacio-datos' name='nombre' type='text' placeholder='Nombre' maxlength='20' required>" +
          "</div>"+

          "<div class='fila'>"+
            "<img src='src/images/svg/icons/id.svg' class='imagen'/>"+
            "<input id='ced' class='espacio-datos' name='num_ident' type='text' placeholder='Cedula' onkeypress='onlyNumbers(event)'>" +
          "</div>"+

          "<div class='fila'>"+
            "<img src='src/images/svg/icons/phone.svg' class='imagen'/>"+
            "<input id='tlf' class='espacio-datos' name='num_telef' type='text' placeholder='Telefono' onkeypress='onlyNumbers(event)'>" +
          "</div>"+
        "</form>",
      preConfirm: function () {        
        var array = {
          'nombre' : $("#name").val(),
          'cedula' : $("#ced").val(),
          'telefono' : $("#tlf").val(),
        }

        return array;
      },
    },
    {
      html:
        "<form action='' method='post'>" + 
          "<div class='main-cont'>"+
            "<span>" +
              "Por favor ingresa el codigo de verificacion NUIP "+
              "que hemos enviado a tu celular" +
            "</span>"+

            "<div class='row cuadros'>" +
              "<input id='num-1' class='inp-num' data-pos='0' type='text' maxlength='1' name='one' onkeypress='isInputNumber(event)' autofocus='autofocus'/>" +
              "<input id='num-2' class='inp-num' data-pos='1' type='text' maxlength='1' name='two' onkeypress='isInputNumber(event)'>" +
              "<input id='num-3' class='inp-num' data-pos='2' type='text' maxlength='1' name='three' onkeypress='isInputNumber(event)'>" +
              "<input id='num-4' class='inp-num' data-pos='3' type='text' maxlength='1' name='four' onkeypress='isInputNumber(event)'>" +
            "</div>" +
          "</div>"+
        "</form>",

      preConfirm: function () {
        return [
          $("#num-1").val(),
          $("#num-2").val(),
          $("#num-3").val(),
          $("#num-4").val(),
        ];
      },
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On sweetalert2 the `inputValidator` function is not called if the modal doesn't have any `input` defined.

A way to workaround that in your case is to add the `input` in the mixin but then hide it using `onBeforeOpen`.

Basically the mixin becomes:

```
 swal.mixin({
    confirmButtonText: 'Siguiente',
    buttonsStyling: false,
    input: 'text'
  })
```

And then you add the following code to each element in the queue array to hide the input text:

```
  onBeforeOpen: function (dom) {
    swal.getInput().style.display = 'none';
  }
```

You can see an implementation of that using your code here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xQxWMN

Comment: Rather than putting then hiding the input field, it would be better just to call `Swal.showValidationMessage('Message')` in the `preConfirm` function. That will prevent the modal from closing.

Answer (score 0):

I have two at the same time. I wanted to extract number and checkbox input. But I could not get any specific answer regarding its release. After a lot of research, I developed my own version that you might find useful.

```js
Swal.fire({
        title              : "Ball Adding",
        html               :
          '<input class="swal2-input" id="rating-number" placeholder="Qo`shiladigan ballni yozing" type="number" style=" width: 80%; ">' +
          '<label for="rating-checkbox" class="swal2-checkbox" style="display: flex;">' +
          '<input type="checkbox" value="1" id="rating-checkbox">' +
          '<span class="swal2-label">Chempionat baliga ham qo`shilsin</span>' +
          '</label>',
        showCancelButton   : true,
        confirmButtonText  : "Qo'shish",
        cancelButtonText   : 'Bekor qilish',
        showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
        preConfirm         : () => {
          console.log('Rating: '+ parseInt(document.getElementById('rating-number').value))
          console.log('Checkbox: '+document.getElementById('rating-checkbox').checked)
          return parseInt(document.getElementById('rating-number').value)
        },
        allowOutsideClick  : () => !Swal.isLoading()
      }).then((result) => {
        if (result.isConfirmed) {
         console.log(result.value+' rating add')
        }
      })
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
```

**I wrote a function for a project in Nuxtjs to update users score. The code of this function.**

```
ratingAdd() {
      Swal.fire({
        title              : "Ball qo'shish",
        html               :
          '<input class="swal2-input" id="rating-number" placeholder="Qo`shiladigan ballni yozing" type="number" style=" width: 80%; ">' +
          '<label for="rating-checkbox" class="swal2-checkbox" style="display: flex;">' +
          '<input type="checkbox" value="1" id="rating-checkbox">' +
          '<span class="swal2-label">Chempionat baliga ham qo`shilsin</span>' +
          '</label>',
        showCancelButton   : true,
        confirmButtonText  : "Qo'shish",
        cancelButtonText   : 'Bekor qilish',
        showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
        preConfirm         : () => {
          return this.$axios.post('user/rating-change-aaa', {
            user_id : parseInt(this.user_id),
            rating  : parseInt(document.getElementById('rating-number').value),
            checkbox: document.getElementById('rating-checkbox').checked
          });
        },
        allowOutsideClick  : () => !Swal.isLoading()
      }).then((result) => {
        if (result.isConfirmed) {
          this.SwalMixin(result.value.data.data.message, 'success')
          this.getUserInfo()
        }
      });
    },
```